# can only join an iterable error on shell scrapy on python scraping

Tags: python, error-handling, scrapy, iterable

I have a simply code for scrapy but i got an error when there is None, see my code below, how can fix it

In [428]:  ''.join(response.css(".prdd-price-first::text").get()).strip()

TypeError: can only join an iterable

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Iterable means your expression to be a list. So you can do something like:

```
''.join([ x.get().strip() for x in response.css(".prdd-price-first::text")])
```